# Aura event namespace lightning component package

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, namespace, unmanaged-package

I went through an example showing contact list search etc.
In the SearchBarController.JS we have this line:

```
var myEvent = $A.get("e.**namespace**:SearchKeyChange");
```

And this works fine where implemented.
Dropping the namespace causes an error.

***1.*** Is it a must to have the namespace when doing Get for an event?

When I try to pack it as un-managed and use it in another org this failed. In debug its null.

***2.*** Do I need to change manually all references from one namespace to another?

---

I tried to pack it as managed and got this error:

> (xxx) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)    There were custom
>   validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s).
>   The first validation error encountered was "{0}".

***3.*** Any idea what can be done?

***4.*** Did anyone try installing managed lightning component/app that has namespace reference?

PS. Saw this: [Deploy Lightning components without namespace](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66687/deploy-lightning-components-without-namespace)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Absolutely

   - e.searchkeychange would be a component event, but since $A.get() is global it doesn't have a context of a component to resolve against, so you must specify the namespace for the event you are trying to access.
2. Yes. Can't map one to another.
3. :( Not sure, that's annoying.
4. Sounds like you're good here.